# Cardinality of the intersection of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> In a graduating class of $236$ students, $142$ took algebra and $121$
>   took chemistry. What is the greatest possible number of students that
>   could have taken both algebra and chemistry?

Let $x$ be that number who took both algebra and chemistry. Those who took algebra only is $142-x$. Those who took chemistry only is $121-x$.

The number of people who took both must be 121.

Then all the people who took chemistry took algebra.

The number of people who only took algebra is $21$, let this number be $B$.
The number of people who took both is $121$, let this number be $C$.

I don't understand how $B+C \neq 236$. I'm adding these two together to verify that the graduating class had 236 students.

How do we verify that the total number of students is $236$?

Is it possible that some of the $236$ students took neither algebra nor chemistry?

Comment: "Is it possible that some of the 236 students took neither algebra nor chemistry?" Unless the problem states otherwise, yes.

Comment: So "236 students in the graduating class" is really just useless information?

Comment: You might look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an answer.

Comment: "Is it possible that some of the 236 students took neither algebra nor chemistry?"  Of course it's possible.  "The number of people who took both must be 121"  It must be at *most* $121$.  It could be fewer.  
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the largest number of students who took both is $\min(142, 121) = 121$. As $142 + 121 \ge 236$, the minimal number is just $-(236 - 142 - 121) = 27$. As a check, there are $142 - 27 = 115$ taking only algebra, $121 - 27 = 94$ taking only chemistry, and $27$ taking both, in all $115 + 94 + 27 = 236$.

Comment: How does one draw the Venn diagram of the process you described?

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill but it should be instructive.

The entirety of students can be broken into four disjoint and exhaustive sets.

$X = A^c \cap C^c$ the students who took neither Albera nor chemistry.

$Y = A\cap C^c$ the students who took Algebra but not chemistry.

$Z = A^c \cap C$ the students who took Chemistry but not algebra.

$W = A \cap C$ the students who took both.

Now we know:

$X + Y + X + W  = 236$

$Y+W = 142$

$Z + W = 121$

We want to solve $W$

$Y= 142 - W; Z= 121-W$ so $236 =X + Y+ Z + W = X +142 -W + 121-W + W = 263 -W$ or in other words

$W = X + 27$

So how many took booth depends entirely on how many took neither.

$W$ can be as little as $27$ if no-one took neither

(In which case $X = A^c \cap C^c = 0$.  $Y= A\cap C^c = 142 - W= 115$.  And $X = A^c \cap C = 121-W = 94$ and $0 + 115 + 94 + 27=236$.)

or as high as ... well ...

Well, $W \le \min(A,C) = 121$.  So if *everybody* who took chemistry took Algebra then we'd have $W =121$ and

$X = W-27 = 94$

(In this case $X=A^c \cap C^c = 94$ who took neither.  $Y=A\cap C^c = 142-W = 21$ which took Algebra only.  $Z=A^c\cap C =121-121= 0$ students took only chemistry. And $W = 121$ who took both And $94 + 21 + 0 + 121= 236$.)

This all leads to the inclusion exclusion principal:

$|A\cup C| =|A| + |C| - |A\cap C|$.  Combine that with $U = (A\cup C)^c \cup (A\cup C)= (A^c\cap C^c) \cup (A\cup C)$ so$|U| = |A^c\cap C^c| + |A\cup C| - |(A^c\cap C^c)\cap(A\cup C)| = |A^c\cap C^c| + (|A| + |C| - |A\cap C|) + 0 = |A^c\cap C^c| + |A| + |C| - |A\cap C|$

Or in other words $236 = |A^c\cap C^c| + 142 + 121 - |A\cap C| = X + 142 + 121 - W$. Or $W = 27 + |X|$ $|X|\ge 0$ and $W\le 121$ so $|X| \le 94$.

Answer (score 0):

The "trick" here is that 236 students being enrolled in the class does not mean that 236 unique students comprise the union of the sets of those who took either class. Because of that, you are just limited by the minimum between the two classes, which is 121.

I understand this question is supposed to "catch" careless readers who assume the question is asking for the minimum number of students, but without assuming that the question is so meritless, you might as well be asking if 2 + 2 = 4.